# Placing figures one above the other

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to place these two figures above one another but so that the timeseries is directly above the heat map. Grid.arrange does not quite align them properly. 
Any ideas?

[image: See image below]

Comment: If you're working with ggplot2, look into [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork)

Comment: try ggarrange from ggpubr package. you can use align = 'v' option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bggplot2%5D+align+plots&mixed=1

Comment: There is lots of different options in the linked duplicate. As DiceboyT says, `patchwork` is a good option here.